# Printing name of the initializing function for a class

Tags: c++, exception

Is it possible to capture and print name of the function which initialized a class object? What I want is something like this:

```
class MyException: public std::exception
{
public:
    MyException(const std::string message, const std::string caller = __func__)
        : _caller(caller),
          _msg(message)
    {
            ...
    }

    std::string what(void); // prints messaged along with the caller
private:
    ...
}
```

In the above class `MyException` I want the caller to capture the function name where an object was instantiated so that user is warned of which function threw. I can always do

```
  ...
  throw MyException(message, __func__);
  ...
```

while removing the default `__func__`. But then I am doing this trivial thing every time I instantiate an `MyException` object.

Is there a better way to instruct user exactly which function throws?

Thanks in advance,

Nikhil

Comment: Only if you explicitly pass it a string containing the name of the function. Unless of course you want to use an unreliable stack trace and parse all of the mapping information that tells you the location of each function. Probably not worth the effort.

Comment: That might be one of the appropriate cases for a macro definition, if you want to avoid writing the boiler plate `__func__`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, As in the above constructor I believe. 

BTW, the above constructor (with `__func__` as default argument) seems to work and I don't have to pass the caller name explicitly, but while it compiles well, I see a warning `Predefined identifier is only valid inside a function`, which I don't like ignoring.

Comment: @NikhilJJoshi: the `__func__` is evaluated at the point of declaration of the constructor, not at each instantiation place. Just pass the information in. You might find it beneficial to define a class to hold source code position, and a macro to create an instance of such (then pass that).

Comment: _seems to work_ is never as good as _absolutely works like i need_. If it did work exactly as you needed and in all situations i doubt you would be asking for a solution.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I did suspect that, however a trial run does show it capturing the instantiating caller name well, but with a compiler warning at the class constructor `Predefined identifier is only valid inside a function`. I believe this warning does instruct why I see it working, but it is a warning I need to care :(.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ and CaptainOblivious, I would like to accept the macro definition as a solution. Thanks :).

Comment: Ps. Suggest you derive your exception from 'std::runtime_error' rather than exception. It already encapsulates the string and implements what() correctly [what() must return a const char *]

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of your class working, albeit with a warning? I certainly cannot [get it to work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9826aa5424f7a7b8). And why are you making those constructor arguments `const`? It has no benefit and you're preventing move optimizations. Assuming you can use C++11, you should be `std::move`ing those arguments into the data members (take a look at my example).

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to provide automatic context for my exceptions I'd do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

struct context_info {
    explicit context_info(std::string function)
    : _function { std::move(function) }
    {}

    // perhaps the context info will increase later to include class and instance?  
    friend std::string to_string(const context_info& ci)
    {
        return ci._function;
    }

private:
    std::string _function;
};

struct my_exception : std::runtime_error
{
    my_exception(const std::string& message)
    : std::runtime_error(message)
    {}

    my_exception(context_info context, const std::string& message)
    : my_exception(message + " called from " + to_string(context))
    {}

    // everything else already taken care of for you
};

#if defined(NDEBUG)
  #define THROW_WITH_CONTEXT(TYPE, ...) throw TYPE(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
  #define THROW_WITH_CONTEXT(TYPE, ...) throw TYPE(context_info(__func__), __VA_ARGS__)
#endif

using namespace std;

void do_foo()
try {
    THROW_WITH_CONTEXT(my_exception, "foo failure");
}
catch(const exception& e) {
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    try {
        do_foo();
        THROW_WITH_CONTEXT(my_exception, "error");
    }
    catch(const exception& e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
foo failure called from do_foo
error called from main
```

However, neat as this is it's probably not what you should really be doing as it won't provide you with enough context in a large complex program.

have a look at the documentation for `std::throw_with_nested` etc. You can catch an exception at each stage of the call stack and re-throw it with additional context information. This is much more useful.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/throw_with_nested